# Text to Binary in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a binary translator - with a *string* as an input and its *binary representation* as output.

And I'm having some difficulties, I wrote in variable the translation for each letter, but they are variables, not strings, so I want to take an input from that matches with the name of the variable and prints the result:

```
a = "01000001"
b = "01000010"
c = "01000011"
d = "01000100"
# all the way to z


word = input("enter here: ")
print (word)
```

When I run this I enter a word and it just returns the same word to me but when I write `print(a)` it returns `01000010` but I can't get it to work with the input.

Can someone tell me where I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: you are printing "word" which is your input.

Comment: You don't describe your difficulties and you didn't ask a question. This is a Q&A site, so a questionmark somewhere in your text would be helpful to locate what you are actually asking. (E.g. If I switch to using Java will this magically work without coding?)

Comment: If I understood well, she wants to print the value of the variable, matching the input with the name of the variable, so if you input the "a" char, you get not the a result, but the 01000001, In my answer I think it works

Comment: `a = "01000001"` etc. - if you mean ASCII codes, yours are for *capital* letters (`A`, `B`, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the comments of the users, is a better practice of programming using a dictionary for these cases, you just only have to fill in the dictionary `letterToBin` as you can see in the example

This is a dictionary, wich means it will have a key, and a value, like a cell phone, you have the key as a name (your mother) and the value (his cellphone):

```
letterToBin = {}

letterToBin = {
  "a" : "01000001", #Here, the key is the "a" letter, and the value, his bin transformation, the 01000001
  "b" : "01000010",
  "c" : "01000011",
  "d" : "01000100"
  #so you need to add all the other keys you need, for example the "e"
  "e" : "01000101" #for example
}




binToLetter = {} # here I create a second dictionary, and it invert the values of the first, it meas, now the keys will be the bins, and the value the latters
binToLetter = dict(zip(letterToBin.values(), letterToBin.keys())) #this code do the magic, you must understand, that only needs to feel the first dictionary, and for free, you will have the second dictionary

wordOrBin = input("enter here: ")

if wordOrBin in letterToBin:
  print(letterToBin[wordOrBin]) #here I has if you write a latter (a) or a bin(11001101) and it choose where to look the correct value
else:
  print(binToLetter[wordOrBin])
```

Comment: thank you so much it finally worked ive been trying for hours thank you

Comment: @ErenBiçer  I have always loved to help, don't forget accept the answer, with the (✓)

Comment: Nice hack, but not a good approach. Using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for the translation table would be the canonical way.

Comment: @Matthias Yes endeed! hahaha, but see, she is new in this programming world, so she would to rewrite all her code again, and there are a lot of keys from a-z... don't you think?

Comment: Nice - but you used the name `x` for the user's input and she used the same name in her "coding table" (`a` thru `z`).

Comment: @DamianLattenero - You are devilishly fast - I am going to upvote your answer now.

Comment: @MarianD ahahahaha I don't know if that a good thing or a bad thing, but thanks! ahahahah

Comment: This is bad advice. You should not be encouraging bad programming design, and using globals dictionary to access variables by name is major code smell.

Comment: @DamianLattenero if you don't mind me asking is there a way to do the reverse? (e.g. i input 01000001 and get a)

Comment: sure @ErenBiçer I will update the answer with a better solution

Comment: @ErenBiçer, I think this is a good solution, look, you just have to complete the first dictionary, with the next letters with that sintaxis, "e" : "1010101", and thats it, you can ask for letters and binaries in both ways

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you are right, I updated the answer with a better solution

Comment: @Matthias I updated the answer following your advices, really better

Comment: @ErenBiçer, Didn't you wanted the other way also? meaning if you input 01100001, you will get the "a" letter? With my solution you can do this

Comment: @DamianLattenero both of them just seem so complicated to me i kind of did understand the first one you wrote

Comment: @ErenBiçer, If you want I can add an explaination of the code

Comment: @DamianLattenero i think the both way translation is a bit too complicated for me i should probably just stick to text to binary. You both explained it good i don't know which one to vote :(

Comment: @ErenBiçer I added some explanaition to the code, you only need to worrie to complete the first dictionary, just as you did to the first, "e" : "1010101", etc etc, and then, you run the code, and you can automatically ask for the inverse question! if you write 01000001, you will get the value "a", for free!

Comment: @DamianLattenero i just can't understand the both way translation is too complicated for me sorry :(

Answer (score 3):

Probably the more correct solution is to use a *dictionary* instead of *names of letters* as *names of variables*:

```
transDict = {
    "a": "01100001",
    "b": "01100010",
    "c": "01100011",
    "d": "01100100",
    # etc., etc.
    }

text   = input( "Enter your message: " )

result = "".join( [transDict[letter] for letter in text] )

print(result)
```

(I also corrected the `ASCII` codes - yours were for *capital* letters.)

---

**The explanation**
(for the longest statement):

"Use `""` as delimiter (i.e. `no delimiter`) to *join* all items in the *list of translated letters* where letters are gotten one after other from the `text`".

So the result will be the same as if you used these commands:

```
listOfCodes = []                     # Starting with an empty list
for letter in text:                  # For letter by letter in text perform 2 actions:
    code = transDict[letter]         #   - translate the letter
    listOfCodes.append( code )       #   - append the translation to the list

result = "".join( listOfCodes )      # Then join items of the list without a delimiter 
                                     # (as "" is an empty string) (" " would be nicer)
```

Comment: MarianD! Nice one, ;) I really like it! +1

Comment: @DamianLattenero - thanks (I am not so fast as you are). Whereas your solution remember me things which I already forgot and more respected the OP original code.

Comment: @DamianLattenero - thanks - I realized that OP is probably not very experienced one, so I added some explanation to my original answer.